# Adding boost to xcode - what files I should include after compilation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, boost

I've compiled boost library, and I received 2 folders after compilation:

-**Include** folder with all headers and .cpp files

-**Lib** folders with .dlyb files and .a files

Which of them I should include to my project? Can I use only .dlyb and .a files without ponting xcode project to headers?

Comment: You need to import the header, no matter what. After u need to use .cpp (but you will need to compile them each time) or static lib (.a), or dynamic lib (.dlyb). But not the 3 of them on the same time.

Comment: @Mr Bonjour, So I can add headers and dynamic libs and XCode won't compile them each time? Am I correct?

Comment: Sure! this is why libs are made for. Static lib are added at link time and dynamic are added at runtime. But watch out, you can't add dynamic libs on a IOS project and you should be be careful at the binary architecture of the library vs your own binary architecture. You should check on Google how to integrate BOOSt on your project, since it is a library very popular, you should find how to rapidly.

Comment: Which boost libraries are you using?  Some of the template libraries require no libraries -- you only need to include the headers